# Why doesn't C have a non blocking sleep function like setTimeout in javascript

Tags: c, timer, x86, sleep

`sleep()` blocks the running thread in C given `x` amount of seconds.
If I'm not mistaking, this can be implemented in 2 ways. Either go in an infinite loop and check the current time with BIOS, if time>=timeout then end the loop.

Second way is to use a timer in CPU and let the timer do the counting async and not block the CPU thread.

Am I correct about the above 2 methods? if so why doesn't C have a function to implant the second way so we can have non-blocking "delays"?

Comment: Because there is no native support to asynchronous computing in C, you have to use a library such as pthread.

Comment: but theoretically speaking, `sleep` could have had an `async` version a swell right? nothing is stopping the hardware from doing it.

Comment: Depends on the hardware. C is designed to be used to program just about anything, from last gen games to 8-pin microcontrollers smaller than a grain of rice, so the language isn't tied to features that would limit it to advanced hardware.

Comment: The question seems to mix up two things: `sleep()` which blocks the *program* (or thread) but hopefully doesn't block the *CPU* (so that other threads or processes can run), and asynchronous timers like the non-ISO `alarm()` that let the program keep running and notify it after a certain length of time.  It is entirely possible for the OS to implement `sleep` in your "second way" without a busy loop, by switching to another process (or halting the CPU) and letting a timer interrupt cause a switch back when the timeout expires.

Comment: Because that requires a thread or an event loop.

Comment: When the timeout ran out, what would happen to the code that was already running? Like, if it was halfway through a printf?

Answer (score 4):

There's another way, which is the one which is usually behind a call to `sleep()`: tell the kernel scheduler to remove this process from the runnable set until the time has expired.

For the function which sets a timer and tells you when it is finished, you can start by looking at [alarm()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html) and [pause()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html). Those aren't in the standard C library, but they have been in Posix for a very long time.

On Windows, you could look at SetTimer.